# Can Entity Framework Core QueryTypes map result to multiple type of objects?

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a new application for my company based on .Net Core and EF Core. I've come across QueryTypes and has been real help to map stored procedures and views  But now I would like to return multiple types with the help of QueryType.

For example I got these two classes:

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Data
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

What I want to do is use a query type that maps the results to these two types:

```
public class TestClass
{
     public Patient Patient { get; set; }
     public Data PatientData { get; set; }
}

// In DbContext I would have something like this
public virtual DbQuery<TestClass> DataDb { get; set; }

// I would call it like a normal dbquery
List<TestClass> result = DataDb.FromSql("....").ToList();
```

Comment: i've not used them yet, only read. However my understanding is that you can create a view or similar for this and it should just map straight to it? i am assuming you have been on the below resource?
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types

Comment: @MrKobayashi Yes I've seen it but it doesn't work for multi-mapping non-entity types. Finally I end up using Dapper Multi Mapping function, that was exactly what i need it. [Dapper Multi-Mapping](https://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping)